# If a function returns an array by reference is it a decay to pointer?

Tags: c++, c++98, cpp-core-guidelines

In the sample code below ComputeSomething() returns a reference to an array.

**I was asked to use C++ core guidelines (NuGet package on MSVC toolchain) as an extra static analysis tool.**

On the return line of `ComputeSomething()` the static analysis tool warns that there is an array to pointer decay. I assume the intent would be to change it in order to make the decay explicit (something like `&(computed_values[0])`) but then that would defeat the point of returning an array by reference.

Is this a valid warning or is it noise, for this specific use-case of returning an array by reference?

**(assumes a C++98 constraint)**

```
float (&ComputeSomething( const seed_t(&seed_data)[num_of_elems_seeded] ))[num_of_elems_calculated]{

    static float computed_values[num_of_elems_calculated];

    // do something...

    return computed_values;
}
```

Comment: Please simplify your code snippets on SO! Nobody needs your namespace, a long list of init vars, your computation, and much much more. You only want to return a reference and get a warning. So please reduce your example to this!

Comment: Read [mcve] for more

Comment: What's up with the extra (pointless) parentheses you put around your functions? That's just weird.

Comment: That is *much* better - but actually, you don't even need the `for` loop.  (which has the additional advantage of removing the need for the argument).

Comment: @JesperJuhl - Are you sure the paren before the `&` is unneeded?  You may well be right, but the syntax for "function returning reference to array" is *very* complex.

Comment: References to arrays are tricksy beasts.  I'd suggest `std::array`, but you say you have a C++98 constraint - in that case, your best bet is `boost::array`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl "  int (&foo())[bar]; " declares a function foo that return a reference to an int array of size bar, I am not sure if this answers your question/comment?

Comment: How do you assign it? That will determine if it decays or not.

Comment: Without seeing how you call the function we can't answer. The function itself returns a reference. If that decays or not should depend on what you do with it.

Comment: @Galik I think you are narrowing on the answer, this is a library method so there is no function call to inspect. if the caller uses a raw "float *foo " then yes there is a decay and the warning is legitimate, if the caller uses "float (&foo)[num_of_elems_calculated]" then it's just static analysis noise. But as you pointed out from library code the tool has no way of making the judgement. I suspect it just triggers if it see "computed_values" used as an lvalue, like in the method return line. Is this what is happening?

Comment: @WishIKnew If you don't actually call this function then I would definitely think it is an error. It looks like the static checker is just looking at the `return` statement and not paying any regard to the return type. Maybe file a bug?

Comment: @Galik I am still finding my way around SO, should I just answer my own question, or would you like to close it?

Comment: You can answer your own question. Others may find this useful.

Comment: There is a very simple rule. Whenever you want to make a function that returns an array - do not.

Comment: @Mikhail thank you for your great point and constructive feedback. I would certainly prefer the pattern of passing it in as a function argument but we do not always have authority over API design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the method below:

```
float (&ComputeSomething())[num_of_elems_calculated]{

    static float computed_values[num_of_elems_calculated];

    // do something...

    return computed_values;
}
```

Unlike what is probably happening in the static analysis tool, the *potential* array to pointer decay is not determined inside the method but instead when the caller calls the function:

```
// expected to decay
float *some_computation = ComputeSomething(); 

// not expected to decay to pointer
float (&safer_computation)[num_of_elems_calculated] = ComputeSomething();
```

Thanks to @Galik for his input on this.

Answer (score -2):

Yes.

In the `ComputeSomething`  function, `computed_values` is an array. And as usual with arrays it can naturally decay to a pointer to its first element.

So the `ComputeSomething` function could be simplified to

```
const float* ComputeSomething(...){ ... }
```

---

To "preserve" size information, then to be able to use the function as it it now, the size needs to be known by the caller *anyway*. It's not something that is automatically transferred. So using a pointer will not change much, unless you absolutely want to use `sizeof` on the array, but that can be sidestepped by using the size you must provide in the variable declaration anyway. Using pointer will most definitely simplify the syntax, and as such also make the code more readable and maintainable.

You could also use `std::vector`, which have built in size information. Or force the upgrade to a more modern compiler which can use C++11, and then use `std::array` if you want to have compile-time fixed-size arrays.

I'm not sure if [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) exists in C++98, or if it came in C++03, but as some kind of middle-ground you could use `std::pair<float*, size_t>` to return both a pointer *and* the size.

Then finally, you could always use `typedef` to create aliases to your array types. Then you don't need to explicitly specify the size everywhere, and it will simplify the syntax quite a lot:

```
typedef computed_values_type[num_of_elems_calculated];

....

computed_values_type& ComputeSomething(...) { ... }

...

computed_values_type& computed_values = ComputeSomething(...);
```

Comment: But by simplifying it to a raw pointer we lose any size information, wish would otherwise be enforced when returning by ref, no?

Comment: @WishIKnew How do you expect to get the size information from the reference?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Something like:  `float (&result)[42] = ComputeSomething(...)'` perhaps?

Comment: ... and if ComputeSomething is not returning a reference to an array of 42 elements, you will get a compile error.

Comment: Or simply `auto& array = ComputeSomething(); int elemtCount = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);`

Comment: This is not correct. The OPs function returns a reference. As long as you assign the returned value to a reference it will not decay.

Comment: either you or OP should update, there is no `MagicLookUp` in the question anymore

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, you are correct I was asked by mods to simplify the sample code (twice!). Not sure what is best practice to make the edits clearer?

Comment: @WishIKnew best pratice is to provide a mcve from the start and not to write an answer unless the question is clear. However, I didnt follow this one and by no means I want to accuse anybody. Moreover, it cannot be avoided that something like this happens. Imho it is just important that answers and question are brought into sync afterwards. Maybe you could have politely asked the answerer to update his answer...

Answer (score -4):

From a compiled binaries point of view, reference to an array is just the same old pointer to the first element. It differs from raw pointer only by type itself, which contains information about array size. It may be used, for instance, for compile-time size checks, compiler warnings or `range-based for` loop

Comment: This neither addresses the question that was asked, nor would it be correct, if it did. What you describe is a plausible implementation, any given C++ compiler might choose. It's not something, that is required, though. A compiler could choose to emit completely different code when returning an array.